# Copy Formatting and Value from one tab to another using script

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have a small issue, I've managed to complete the first part of the script I wanted. I have this sheet as follows

First tab : Input

A2:AA38 There are data that I input every week. The row range changes weekly depending on factors. Meaning it can be A2:AA35 some weeks while others A2:AA42

Second tab : Output

Where data from "Input" are added automatically when script is run and it will leave 2 lines from last week's entry. I have got this part worked out. It's working great and fine

```
function writeData () {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var inSheet = ss.getSheetByName("input");
var input = inSheet.getRange(1, 1, inSheet.getLastRow(), 26).getValues();
var outSheet = ss.getSheetByName("output");
var outStartRow = outSheet.getLastRow() + 2;

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
  outSheet.getRange(outStartRow + i, j + 1)
    .setValue(input[i][j]);

}
```

My Problem is that it copies but it does not copy the formatting, so I've been searching around on Google Script library and found a few that could do it but I can't seem to integrate it.

```
  }
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source2 = ss.getSheetByName("input");
  var destination2= ss.getSheetByName("output");
  var range2 = source2.getRange(1, 1, inSheet.getLastRow(), 5).getValues();
  var outSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("output");
  range2.copyFormatToRange(outSheet2, 4, 6, 4, 6); 
  }
```

I've tried this but i'm pretty sure it does not work. I've found that some format such as

```
 copyFormatToRange
 copyTo(destination)
```

But since I am very new to scripting, I can't figure out how to implement it into my existing script.Please help me out.

Figured it out the whole code is like this now:

```
   function writeData () {
   var sss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var inSheet2 = sss.getSheetByName("input");
   var input2 = inSheet2.getRange(1, 1, inSheet2.getLastRow(), 42);
   var outSheet2 = sss.getSheetByName("Schedule List");
    var outStartRow2 = outSheet2.getLastRow() + 2;
   var outStartRow3 = outSheet2.getLastRow() + 2;
   input2.copyFormatToRange(outSheet2, 1, 42, outStartRow3, outStartRow2);                                

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var inSheet = ss.getSheetByName("input");
   var input = inSheet.getRange(1, 1, inSheet.getLastRow(), 42).getValues();
   var outSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule List");
   var outStartRow = outSheet.getLastRow() + 2;


   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
  outSheet.getRange(outStartRow + i, j + 1)
  .setValue(input[i][j]);
   }
   }
  }
```

I know, a bit messy but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

Instead of:

```
var range2 = source2.getRange(1, 1, inSheet.getLastRow(), 5).getValues();
```

it should be:

```
var range2 = source2.getRange(1, 1, inSheet.getLastRow(), 5);
```

that is remove .getValues()

Comment: Yeah I was just coming to post my own answer but you got it. I did this 

  var input2 = inSheet2.getRange(1, 1, inSheet2.getLastRow(), 42);